# Typescript-Angular5 : Compilation issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I try to make implement a login feature with angular5 but I am facing many issues. I resolved some of them and now I have a compilation problem:

```
ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts(38,3): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Boolean'.
  Types of property 'valueOf' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.
      Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I understand the error but I don't know how to resolve it and make my code work.
Here is the login.component.ts class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../auth/user.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  ngForm: NgForm;
  login: string;
  password: string;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  isLoginError : boolean = false;
  connected : Boolean = false;
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

// Execute this when submit login form
OnSubmit(form){

    console.log(form.value);
    console.log(form.value.login);
  this.connected =   this.userService.authenticate(form.value.login,form.value.password).subscribe((data : any)=>{
    return data.password = form.value.password;
    //return true;
  });
```

}
  }

The line 38 corresponds at is.connected =   `this.userService.authenticate(form.value.login,form.value.password).subscribe((data : any)=>{`

In user.service.ts I have the authenticate method:

```
authenticate(login:string, password:string) :Observable<Boolean> {
console.log('Authenticate ....');
const credentials = {login:login, password:password};
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
console.log('Appended content type ....');
console.log(' Login '+login+' Password '+password+' Headers '+headers);
//var data = this.http.get<any>(
//              '/users?login?'+JSON.stringify(login),
//               { headers }
//);
//console.log('Data '+data);
  return this.http.get<any>(
                '/users?login?'+JSON.stringify(login),
                 { headers }
  ) //returns a User object having password
    .map(user => user.password === password); // maps result to the desired true or false value

}
```

How to resolve my error and make my code works?

Comment: Did you want to set a variable or compare: `return data.password = form.value.password;` - or did you mean `return data.password == form.value.password;` or `return data.password === form.value.password;`

Comment: And, you cannot save the result into `this.connected` that way... `this.connected` could be of type Subscription to save the observable-subscription (to unsubscribe later/in onDestroy)

Comment: `subscribe((data : any)=>{ ....` I think the result of the observable will be inside data (see @Mixalloff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `connected` variable inside subscribe

```
this.userService.authenticate(form.value.login,form.value.password)
  .subscribe((isPasswordsMatch : boolean)=>
    this.connected = isPasswordsMatch;
  );
```

Comment: @Pracede, maybe `this.connected = (data.password === form.value.password)`? you do not have to return anything from inside the subscribe callback...

Comment: Yes, it looks more logical. I'm edit my answer. But error occured due to incorrect assignment

Comment: Thank you for your answer but now i have another error on form login at this line <form (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(loginForm)" #loginForm="ngForm">. The error is ERROR 
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
Do you know why ?

Comment: @Pracede, can you compare your `ngSubmit` with the docs? https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Comment: You need a method in your TS file matching the `OnSubmit(loginForm)` definition...

Comment: It strange..The `data` in subscription is not a object, it is `boolean`. But it   should throw error in compiltation time, not in runtime. And your error not linked with it. You can try to fix it and rebuild the project...